# Exception report when this.getServletConfig() if I have ServletConfig member variable

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, servletconfig

When I run :

```
Enumeration<String> enums = this.getServletConfig().getInitParameterNames();
```

I get the `HTTP Status 500` error in my broswer.

> HTTP Status 500 -
>
> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       com.ypd.config.ConfigDemo.doGet(ConfigDemo.java:32)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M17 logs.
>   Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M17

The snapshot:

[image]

My config code in `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ConfigDemo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ypd.config.ConfigDemo</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>path</param-name>
        <param-value>/Users/luowensheng/Downloads/图片1.png</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>aaa</param-name>
        <param-value>aaa's value</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ConfigDemo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/configDemo</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And in my `ConfigDemo.java`:

```
public class ConfigDemo extends HttpServlet{

    private ServletConfig config;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

        this.config = config;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Enumeration<String> enums = this.getServletConfig().getInitParameterNames(); // this is 32th line, here I get the error.
        while(enums.hasMoreElements()) {
            String paramName = enums.nextElement();
            String paramValue = this.getServletConfig().getInitParameter(paramName);

            resp.getWriter().write(paramName + "=" + paramValue);

        }

    }
}
```

But in the end I found if I annotation the below code, there will not have the error：

```
private ServletConfig config;

@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

    this.config = config;
}
```

Why? why can not have this ServletConfig member variable here?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of a Servlet where the call to `getServletConfig` returns `null`.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, this line:`Enumeration<String> enums = this.getServletConfig().getInitParameterNames();` I annotation at the end , here I get the issue.

Comment: The problem in the duplicate is different but the answer is the same. If you're going to override `init`, you must invoke its super implementation. Your `init` is useless though, just remove it.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, wao, nice anser, thank you very much.